# PuTTY option "Implicit LF in every CR" does not work in Plink

Tags: newline, putty, plink

When using a session in PuTTY with option "Implicit LF in every CR" enabled, I can see in Wireshark that it is working fine and sending CR + LF for each CR sent.

Using Plink with `plink <my_session_name>` everything seems fine: host and port settings from my session are used but the option "Implicit LF in every CR" is not used and only CR is sent.

Is it something normal? Is this option only supported in PuTTY interactive mode?

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's not supported in Plink.

The *"Implicit LF in every CR"* is a terminal feature. There's no terminal emulation in Plink.

If you want the CRLF in Plink, you have to send the CRLF explicitly. You can implement a wrapper console application that runs the Plink and passes all its input to Plink, transparently translating the CR to the CRLF.

Comment: That is what I did but it does not work, when I send CRLF to plink it is translated to CR, same for LFCR translated to CR, so there should be something doable in plink...at least I hope !

Comment: How do you run plink? What command-line arguments do you use? Only the session name? Or anything else?

Comment: Yes, only the session name where host & port is used. I also set mode as raw mode in my session.

Comment: Raw mode? So you do not use SSH?

Comment: Right this is for a "telnet like" session to talk to a specific device.

Comment: How do you run the Plink? From what language, etc?

Comment: I'm using TCL but it's the same when running plink interactively, that is, starting plink and typing blindly the keyboard, characters are never received on the other side. Wireshark confirms that only CR are sent.

Comment: Launching Plink to "implement" a trivial socket communication is overkill. Use native support for the sockets of your language. See http://wiki.tcl.tk/15315

Comment: Well, I'm using Expect in Tcl so that's not overkill since it's designed for driving non GUI application. Please consider that my problem can be reduced to what I've first wrote. Using session and CRLF plink does not act properly.

Comment: I understand that. But your solution is wrong. I've tried to give you a solution suitable for Stack Overflow (programming). The problem that you have described in your question is actually not programming question at all. It should be asked at [su].